# Getting name of button clicked in POST

Tags: vue.js

In Vue, I've tried naming buttons, but after the submit, the data isn't posted.

```
   <div id="app">
      <form ref="myForm" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit($event)" action="/push" class="needs-validation" id="myForm" novalidate="true">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cannedListLabel">Canned List</label>
          <input v-model="cannedlist" ref="cannedlist" type="text" class="form-control" name="fileListFile" id="filelist"
         :disabled="!!individuallist" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pathListLabel">Path List</label>
          <textarea v-model="individuallist" ref="cannedlist" :disabled="!!cannedlist" class="form-control" rows=10 name="fileListRaw" id="files"></textarea>
        </div>            
        <div class="form-group">
          <button v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit($event)" type="submit" name="button1" value="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="isDisabledButton">Submit</button>
          <button v-model="clickedButton" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit($event)" type="submit" name="button2" value="checkOnly" id="checkOnlyButton" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="isDisabledButton">Check Only</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

The onSubmit function submits the form using this.$refs.myForm.submit(); If I change the type of the button from "submit" to "button", the submit() function no longer works, which I don't completely understand. Why is that, by the way?

As suggested, I change the type to button, and used the @click handler and while it does not work, here's changed diff:

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <button @click="onSubmit($event)" type="button" name="btn" value="submitButtonPressed" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" :disabled="isDisabledButton">Submit</button>
          <button @click="onSubmit($event)" type="button" name="btn" value="checkOnlyButtonPressed" id="checkOnlyButton" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="isDisabledButton">Check Only</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Because the event of a submit type button is "submit", while the one of a normal button is "click". Semantically a form has one submit action that submits the entire form, but can have multiple other buttons that just add extra functionality without submitting the form itself.

Comment: I guess my question was, why doesn't this submit call work if I change the button type to button?

Comment: Because v-on:submit will never get triggered on a non-submit button. You've got to use @click instead.

Comment: I still can't get the button name, by changing the type to "button" and using @clock as you suggested; Printing out r.Form yields nothing pertaining to the button pressed.

Comment: I was referring to the question regarding changing from submit to button. Besides that you've given little information of what exactly is not working except that you someone "can't get the name" of a button without providing any code or background information on that.

Comment: I'll add the actual code for what is being called.